# Window in window term

Tags: windows-xp, window, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know what it is called when a window is inside another window, and constrained only to inside said host window? I remember some system utility in XP having this, and now I want to develop a Visual Basic program with this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What it is called when a window is inside another window, and constrained to the host window?

That will be an example of Windows MDI (Multiple Document Interface):

> **Frame, Client, and Child Windows**
>
> An MDI application has three kinds of windows: a frame window, an MDI
>   client window, as well as a number of child windows. The frame window
>   is like the main window of the application: it has a sizing border, a
>   title bar, a window menu, a minimize button, and a maximize button.
>   The application must register a window class for the frame window and
>   provide a window procedure to support it.
>
> An MDI application does not display output in the client area of the
>   frame window. Instead, it displays the MDI client window. An MDI
>   client window is a special type of child window belonging to the
>   preregistered window class MDICLIENT. The client window is a child of
>   the frame window; it serves as the background for child windows. It
>   also provides support for creating and manipulating child windows. For
>   example, an MDI application can create, activate, or maximize child
>   windows by sending messages to the MDI client window.
>
> When the user opens or creates a document, the client window creates a
>   child window for the document. The client window is the parent window
>   of all MDI child windows in the application. Each child window has a
>   sizing border, a title bar, a window menu, a minimize button, and a
>   maximize button. Because a child window is clipped, it is confined to
>   the client window and cannot appear outside it.
>
> An MDI application can support more than one kind of document. For
>   example, a typical spreadsheet application enables the user to work
>   with both charts and spreadsheets. For each type of document that it
>   supports, an MDI application must register a child window class and
>   provide a window procedure to support the windows belonging to that
>   class. For more information about window classes, see Window Classes.
>   For more information about window procedures, see Window Procedures.
>
> Following is a typical MDI application. It is named Multipad.
>
> [image]

Source [About the Multiple Document Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644908(v=vs.85).aspx)

---

#### I want to develop a Visual Basic program with this function.

Take a look at [Multiple-Document Interface (MDI) Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa263481(v=vs.60).aspx):

> **Creating an MDI Application**
>
> Use the following procedure to create an MDI form and its child forms.
>
> To create an MDI application
>
> - Create an MDI form.
> - From the Project menu, choose Add MDI Form.
>
>   Note   An application can have only one MDI form. If a project
>     already has an MDI form, the Add MDI Form command on the Project menu
>     is unavailable.
> - Create the application's child forms.
> - To create an MDI child form, create a new form (or open an existing one) and set its MDIChild property to True.

See also [MDI Application](https://free-visualbasic-tutor.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/mdi-application.html) which contains a walk-through for creating a VB 6.0 MDI Editor.